# Getting proxy settings in vs-code programatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vs-code extension in typescript. In my extension I'm sending HTTP requests to an external server. The requirement is as following - The HTTP requests shall pass through the proxy configured in vs-code settings -> Application -> Proxy.

How can I get vs-code proxy settings programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the settings name you need change the setting and look in the `settings.json` file for the exact name.

Use this name in a call to `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration`

Comment: `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().get("http.proxy")` did the trick. Thanks!